# Unity: How can I find the center position of a particular triangle?

Tags: unity, mesh, face, position

I need to face an object from a central point directly through any one of many triangles which are faces on an icosphere whose position is centered on that point. Is there a way to get the center position of the triangle itself, even though its position is the position of the larger object of which it is a part?

Comment: Remember that a triangle has [at least four different "centers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_center), so we need to be more specific. Do you want the centroid? Presumably you tried simply averaging the vertex positions? Where did you run into trouble expressing this in your code?

Comment: Yes, I do in fact want the centroid. You'll have to forgive my public education; we never covered that. But then, when you say I could just average the vertices, it seems obvious enough that I probably should have thought of it. I was more looking for a property of a mesh, but I wasn't finding it in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There are actually tens of thousands of well defined triangle centers](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/etc.html).

The centroid is always a safe and fast center, which is simply the sum of the 3 points which define the triangle, divided by 3 (or multiplied by 1/3rd, which is the faster operation)